# How do I add a string input to an array?

Tags: vb.net

basically i need to add a name to an array of candidates for an election. the user enters the candidates names, and i want to store them in an array. so far i have this:

```
        Dim CandidateNames(candidates) As String
        Dim x As Integer

        'entering the names of each candidate so students can vote for them.
        For x = 1 To candidates
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a candidates name:")
            CandidateNames(candidates) = Console.ReadLine()
        Next
        For x = 0 To candidates - 1
            Console.WriteLine(CandidateNames(candidates) & " is candidate " & x)
        Next
```

i want to then output all the names, which is what the second for loop does, but it only outputs the last entered name.
im in my second GCSE year of computer science, having never done any programming before so go easy on me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code:

```
    Dim candidates as Integer 
    candidates=5
  Dim CandidateNames(candidates) As String
  Dim x As Integer
  
    For x = 0 To candidates
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a candidates name:")
        CandidateNames(x) = Console.ReadLine()
    Next
    
    For x = 0 To candidates
        Console.WriteLine(CandidateNames(x) & " is candidate ")
    Next
```

In your code, you are not storing and accessing the strings correctly.

Comment: this code worked perfectly. i already 'dim-ed' the candidates as an integer at the beggining of my code. where youve used "candidatenames(x)" i had "candidatenames(candidates)", so i think that was my issue. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code.  The first is with your loop bounds: the first loop is this:

```
For x = 1 to candidates
```

And the second loop is this:

```
For x = 0 to candidates - 1
```

In .NET, the lower bound for one-dimensional arrays is always 0 (insert rant about .NET array indexing design choices here), so you should be starting from 0 as in the second loop.  I can never remember if VB arrays specify the upper bound or the count when you declare them, but conceptually the second is correct for the final index: if you want an array of *n* items, then it will be indexed from 0 to *n* - 1.

The second issue is that inside each loop, you are referring to `CandidateNames(candidates)` instead of `CandidateNames(x)`.  Instead of moving through each item in the loop in turn, you are only operating on the last item in the array.

Unless this is for an assignment requiring to use arrays, I'd suggest you consider using `List(Of String)` instead.  Arrays make sense for a more limited set of uses cases, and I don't think this is one of them.  Usually, the number of candidates for an election will be variable; with a list, you can have the user enter candidates until they're done, and the list will automatically expand as you go.  Then, you can use a `For Each` loop to write out the contents of the list (though note you could use a `For Each` loop with an array as well).  A list can still be accessed by index like an array.